# Implement Command Pattern with MDI Form

Tags: c#, command-pattern

I need some advice. I am just trying to learn about the design pattern.
I have tried searching and reading, however I feel lost.
I really hope you can give a suggestion to me.

here I try to attach some pictures and my code :

1. [MDI Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IC4ak.png)

   ```
   private void ItemAddNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       InvokeDataCommand.Instance().SetCommand(new CommandDataManipulation(ActiveMdiChild as IDataManipulation, DataManipulations.Append));
       InvokeDataCommand.Instance().ExecuteCommand();
   }
   ```
2. Interface

   ```
    public interface ICommand {
       void Execute();
    }

    public interface IDataManipulation {
       void Append();
       void Modify();
       void Remove();
    }

    public interface IDataReload {
       void Reload();
    }
   ```
3. Concreate Object

   ```
   public class CommandDataManipulation : ICommand {
       private IDataManipulation __receiver;
       private DataManipulations __action;

       public CommandDataManipulation(IDataManipulation receiver, DataManipulations action) {
           __receiver = receiver ;
           __action = action;
       }

       public void Execute() {
           if (__receiver == null) return;
           if (__action == DataManipulations.Append) __receiver.Append();
           if (__action == DataManipulations.Modify) __receiver.Modify();
           if (__action == DataManipulations.Remove) __receiver.Remove();
       }
   }

   public class CommandDataReload : ICommand {
       private IDataReload     __receiver;

       public CommandDataReload(IDataReload receiver) {
           __receiver = receiver ;
       }

       public void Execute() {
           if (__receiver == null) return;
           __receiver.Reload();
       }
   }
   ```
4. Invoker

   ```
    public class InvokeDataCommand {

       private static InvokeDataCommand __instance;
       private ICommand __command;

       private InvokeDataCommand() {
            __instance = null;
        }

       public static InvokeDataCommand Instance() {
           if (__instance == null) {
               __instance = new InvokeDataCommand();
           }

           return __instance;
       }

       public void SetCommand(ICommand command) {
           __command = command;
       }

       public void ExecuteCommand() {
           __command.Execute();
       }
    }
   ```
5. Receiver

   ```
   public partial class Display : Form, IDataManipulation, IDataReload { 
     ...
   }
   ```

I feel in addition to using the command I also use a singleton.

What have I done now is correct ?